# RestAPI response shows duplicate data

Tags: spring-boot, rest, spring-data-jpa

I'm trying to write a simple application with a One-to-Many association. When I fetch the Author, I repated data multiple times in the Postman response. Below are my entities and mapping.

```
@Entity
public class Books extends AbstractEntity implements Serializable{
    

  // properties

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "auther_number", referencedColumnName="auther_id")
    private Author author;

 // get/set goes here.
}

@Entity
public class Author extends AbstractEntity implements Serializable{

// properties for autherID, name etc.

@OneToMany(mappedBy = "author",cascade = CascadeType.ALL,orphanRemoval = true, fetch = FetchType.LAZY) 
private List<Books> bookList;


// to avoid synchronization issues. in 1-M Bi-direactional
    public void addBooks(Books book) {
        booklist.add(book);
        book.setAuther(this);
    }

    // to avoid synchronization issues. in 1-M Bi-direactional
    public void removeBooks(Books book) {
        booklist.remove(book);
        book.setAuthor(null);
    }

  // equals and hashcode methods

}
```

AutherserviceImpl.java

```
@Override
public List<Author> getAllAuthors() {
        List<Author> authorList = (list<Author>) authorRepo.findAll();
        return authorList  ;        
}
```

RestController

```
  @GetMapping("/api/authors") 
    public ResponseEntity<Object> findAllAuthors(){
                  
        return new ResponseEntity<>(autherserviceImpl.getAllAuthors(),
          HttpStatus.OK);
    }
```

Below is the output in postman. Why is it duplicating? I have followed the samples given by [this](https://www.baeldung.com/jpa-join-column).

```
"authorNo": 4575600302,
"balance": 4458.0,
"books": [
    {
        "bookID": 3522,
        "price": 458.0,
        "ISBN": "1234",
        "author": {
            "authorNo": 4575600302,
            "balance": 4458.0,
            "books": [
                {
                    "bookID": 3522,
                    "price": 458.0,
                    "ISBN": "1234",
                    "author": {
                        "authorNo": 4575600302,
                        "balance": 4458.0,
                        "books": [
                            {
                                "bookID": 3522,
                                "price": 458.0,
                                "ISBN": "1234",
                                "author": {
                                    "authorNo": 4575600302,
                                    "balance": 4458.0,
                                    "books": [
                                        {
```

Some questions in StackOverflow have suggested using Set instead of the list. But when I use Set, I get a casting error between Set and List. Not sure where is it throuwing exactly to fix the casting error. as I do not see any stack trace but only in the postman response I get that error.

How can I resolve this duplicate data showing issue? Note that in the Database has no duplicate records.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is not JPA but the serialization of the author instance by Jackson. You have a bidirectional relationship between the authors and the books, i.e. Jackson serializes all books of an author and when it serializes a book, it will start the process of serializing the respective author again.

The simplest solution is to annotate the field `author` of `Books` with `@JsonIgnore`. Alternatively, you can annotate `author` with `@JsonManagedReference` and the field `bookList` of `Author` with `@JsonBackReference`. Then, the deserialization circle should be broken.

For a detailed guide, please have a look here: https://www.baeldung.com/jackson-bidirectional-relationships-and-infinite-recursion

Comment: Thank you so much. just adding `@JsonIgnore` worked. no more duplicates.